# why android g+ revokeAccessAndDisconnect still keep my g+ permission

Tags: android, oauth, google-plus

I am using G+ login for my app.I have a option for user to disconnect g+ account.

```
 case R.id.action_disconnect:
            disconnectDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            disconnectDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.disconnect_dialog));
            disconnectDialog.show();
            googleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
            googleApiClient.connect();
```

---

```
    private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
            .addScope(new Scope("email"))
            .build();
}

public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(googleApiClient);
    Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
            if (disconnectDialog != null)
                disconnectDialog.dismiss();
            accManager.Log();;
        }

    });
}
```

**accManager.log** return app to login screen.

`Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(googleApiClient)`; clears user account and I verified as I need to select account again when I click g+ login.

but  **`Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(googleApiClient)`** does not revoke my app permission as when I click g+ login with same account only ask me to select account but does not ask for permission.

When I login as a new account app ask for my g+ permission

also uninstalling and `reinstall` my app still keep my g+ permission.
Does any guys meet this issue?Any help would be greatly appreciated. I followed https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer

buildGoogleApiClient should be

```html
    private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
        return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addScope(new Scope("email"))
                .build();
    }
```